# Ruby code to parse and analyze social media stats in json format

Tags: ruby, parsing

What do you think about this code I wrote.
It reads several json files ( I attached them as pastebins)
and the code outputs summary information calculated from the input.

```
# 1) calculate the
# engagement rate from the first JSON file (the user's Instagram media)
# - Calculate the average number of comments - Calculate the average
# number of likes - Calculate the engagement rate using (Average Likes +
# Average Comments)/# of Followers which is 435
# 
# 2) Combine the 2 sets of JSON data (Instagram media objects with their
# Instagram insights), then output a single JSON file where the insights
# are paired with their media objects in a clean format.
#
# Question 1.json: https://pastebin.com/V3Ue87H4
# Question2A.json: https://pastebin.com/YifXzimZ
# Question2B.json: https://pastebin.com/6X0JYXtD

require 'json'
input = JSON.parse( File.read('Question 1.json') )["data"]
avg_likes    = input.map { |x| x["like_count"] }.    inject{ |sum, el| sum + el }.to_f / input.size
avg_comments = input.map { |x| x["comments_count"] }.inject{ |sum, el| sum + el }.to_f / input.size
puts "Answer for Question 1: #{avg_likes + avg_comments / 435}\n\n"


input_a = JSON.parse( File.read('Question2A.json') )["data"]
input_b = JSON.parse( File.read('Question2B.json') ).map { |x| x["data"] }.flatten
output = input_a.map do |post|
  {
    :permalink => post["permalink"],
    :impressions => input_b.find { |x| x["id"] == "#{post['id']}/insights/impressions/lifetime" }["values"][0]["value"],
    :engagement  => input_b.find { |x| x["id"] == "#{post['id']}/insights/engagement/lifetime"  }["values"][0]["value"],
    :reach       => input_b.find { |x| x["id"] == "#{post['id']}/insights/reach/lifetime"       }["values"][0]["value"],
    :saved       => input_b.find { |x| x["id"] == "#{post['id']}/insights/saved/lifetime"       }["values"][0]["value"]
  }
end
puts "Answer for Question 2: " + JSON.pretty_generate(output)


# EXAMPLE OUTPUT - generated by running ruby coding_test.rb
#
# Answer for Question 1: 22.704827586206896
# 
# Answer for Question 2: [
#   {
#     "permalink": "https://www.instagram.com/p/B40LKjkAlDV/",
#     "impressions": 236,
#     "engagement": 33,
#     "reach": 187,
#     "saved": 2
#   },
#   {
#     "permalink": "https://www.instagram.com/p/B4z4Vq5Ag5g/",
#     "impressions": 212,
#     "engagement": 22,
#     "reach": 170,
#     "saved": 0
#   },
#   {
#     "permalink": "https://www.instagram.com/p/B4xnmtygmi-/",
#     "impressions": 297,
#     "engagement": 28,
#     "reach": 218,
#     "saved": 1
#   },
#   {
#     "permalink": "https://www.instagram.com/p/B4uyfrLgjVi/",
#     "impressions": 248,
#     "engagement": 21,
#     "reach": 194,
#     "saved": 0
#   },
#   {
#     "permalink": "https://www.instagram.com/p/B4nic12AFps/",
#     "impressions": 292,
#     "engagement": 15,
#     "reach": 219,
#     "saved": 0
#   }
# ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good work.

Here are some points where you can improve:

- You can use `input.sum { |x| x["like_count"] }.to_f` instead of `input.map { |x| x["like_count"] }.inject{ |sum, el| sum + el }`
- It is a good idea to do calculations with `BigDecimal` instead of `Float`.
- `435` is a magic number, you can put it into a constant with a good name.
- The spaces before the parentheses aren't usual in the Ruby community style guide.
- Check the `dig` method available for `Hash` instances.
- You can use the new syntax for `Hash` instances when the keys are symbols: `{ hello: "world" }`
- Use double-quotes or single-quotes, you're mixing both.